# Fixed size of figure window

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

how I can fix the size of figure window such that user can't manually maximize or minimize it? It means that the window size of figure is always the same.

I know how to change the size of figure, but don't understand how to fix the size of window.

Answer (score 4):

Set the figure's [`'Resize'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#buiwuyk-1-Resize) property to `'off'`. If `f` is the figure handle,

```
set(f, 'Resize', 'off')
```

Or set it directly when you create the figure:

```
f = figure('Resize', 'off');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to overide the `function resize(FigH, EventData, AxesH)` to disable the resizing ... I never had to do this, I usually fix the size to a full screen or squarish for my results in research papers.

Comment: “I usually fix the size” How do you do this? That is exactly the question being asked...